# trouble using python requests to POST to django 1.8 server

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I tried using session and grabbing the cookie.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get(myurl)
csrf = s.cookies['csrftoken']
```

The get had status_code 200 as expected.  Then I first tried just a post on the session hoping that the session would do magic.  (yeah I know better)

```
r = s.post(myurl, json=mydata)
```

which gives a status_code of 405.  And yes, before I forget I have the django settings

```
CSRF_HEADER_NAME='HTTP_X_CSRFToken'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

and my view function is marked with @csrf-exempt as well.  The view function is known to accept post from my Angular frontend as long as I have 'X-CSRFToken=csrf'  where csrf is as in the above setting.  So I tried

```
r = s.post(myurl, json=mydata, headers={'X-CSRFToken':csrf})
```

as well with the same result of 405.  I read that it might help to set the referer to the url so I tried that as well.

```
r = s.post(myurl, json=mydata, headers={'X-CSRFToken':csrf, 'Referrer: url})
```

and still got 405.  So what is the correct way to make this work?

Comment: 405 is method not allowed. This means that your django server is not ready for POST requests in principle. Problems with CSRF and CORS returns 403 - Forbidden.  Problem should be on the server.

Comment: Your capitalisation in the setting is incorrect. It should be `CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'`. The capitalization in the Javascript does not matter, but I believe it does for the setting.

Comment: Tthose settings work fine for posting from Angular.  So they are valid server settings.  Thus it would be very surprising if the server demanded different settings depending on the kind of client making a request.